# Order Nested DataTable in List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects where one of the properties is a datatable. I would like to order the datatables by a specific column later on. I this possible via linq?

Object structure is:

```
string fieldType;
string fieldSource;
DataTable content;
```

Datatable structure is : UpdateDate, Value, Period

I have come up with the below solution for a non linq version

```
foreach (var result in objList)
{
    var dv = result.content.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "UpdateDate desc";
    result.DataPoints = dv.ToTable();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us, what is in objList ?

Comment: Can you try using OrderByDescending. Like objList.Content.OrderByDescending(x=>x.UpdateDate);